# How To Access UITableView.visibleCells Every Time New Cell Emerge

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView displaying `[Double]`. Very Simple. But I also wanna *display the average of the onscreen numbers on every row, and the difference between this number and the average*.

[image]

Because I need to re-calculated the average every time a new row appears, I'm thinking about accessing `tableView.visibleCells` in `cellForRowAt: indexPath` method, and then update the average of this row and every other rows on screen, because the average of onscreen rows should be the same for all the onscreen rows.

But then I got this ***error message*** `[Assert] Attempted to access the table view's visibleCells while they were in the process of being updated, which is not allowed. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForVisibleCellsAccessDuringUpdate to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur. Perhaps you are trying to ask the table view for the visible cells from inside a table view callback about a specific row?`

While this is loud and clear, I'm wondering what is the correct way or workaround for this?

Code is very simple

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var data:[Double] = [13,32,43,56,89,42,26,17,63,41,73,54,26,87,64,33,26,51,99,85,57,43,30,33,20]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "default")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
        print(tableView.visibleCells.count) // THIS LINE PRODUCE ERROR
        return cell    
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 64
    }
    
}
```

***What I have tried:***

I've tried `didEndDisplaying` and `willDisplay`, when I added `print(tableView.visibleCells.count)` to either of them, same error message was given back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer:

You can use UITableView's delegate functions to calculate this.

`tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` is called every time before cell becomes visible, so you can recalculate your average value at this moment. Also, there is `tableView(_:didEndDisplaying:forRowAt:)` which fires when cell goes off display and also can be used to recalculate.

---

### Documentation:

[tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview)

[tableView(_:didEndDisplaying:forRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614870-tableview)

---

### UPD:

For calculation use [tableView.indexPathsForVisibleItems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618020-indexpathsforvisibleitems)

---

### Example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var data:[Double] = [13,32,43,56,89,42,26,17,63,41,73,54,26,87,64,33,26,51,99,85,57,43,30,33,20]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    private func calculate() {
        let count = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.count
        let sum = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?
            .map { data[$0.row] }
            .reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
        
        if let count = count, let sum = sum {
            print(sum / Double(count))
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "default")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 64
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        calculate()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        calculate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I forgot to mention, I tried them. They both produced the same error message when I try to print visibleCells.count. I'm pretty new to stack overflow, i'll add this to my OP. Thank you.

Comment: @Goatt Sorry, now I've update my answer so it solves your problem.

Comment: It worked great! Thank you! Can I ask a follow-up question? Is `self.tableView.reloadData()` necessary in `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: @Goatt I really don't know, I need to do some research to answer. Will come back soon. (I use it always automatically :))

Comment: I'm not sure if you still have time to look at this question. But I tried your code recently and realize that my main problem got solve only partially. You solve the part that I want to track down the cells onscreen and calculate the average. But you haven't solve the part that the result should change every cell onscreen to reflect the new average and their difference. I can't figure out how to trigger every cell onscreen to reload data every time a new cell appear.

Comment: @Goatt One of the best practices for this is using RxSwift. Did you ever try it? I can implement solution for you using it.

Comment: No I don't have experience with it. But I'll look into the reactive solutions. Thanks for the new idea and thanks for coming back.